# PHPMailer could not instantiate on localhost only

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpmailer

I have this weird problem and I cannot find any correct fix for it. I'm using port 8080 or localhost:8080 as my port because port 80 is already used, I dont know if there's a difference in php.ini in that case. Here's my code:

```
    require("../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    //PHPMailer Object
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //From email address and name
    $mail->From = "rangeles@guess.com.ph";
    $mail->FromName = "Raquel Angeles";

    //To address and name
    $mail->addAddress("jabril@guess.com.ph"); //Recipient name is optional

    //Address to which recipient will reply
    $mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply");

    //CC and BCC
    //$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
    //$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

    //Send HTML or Plain Text email
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
    $mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    }
```

My php.ini goes like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP=localhost
smtp_port=25
```

Thank you guys for all your help!

Comment: What error message is returned when PHPMailer fails to send? Do you have a mail server running on localhost?

Comment: your php.ini  are not used by phpmailer. what's `$mail->Host ` set to?

Comment: phpmailer will use the php `mail()` and the php.ini configuration unless `$mail->isSMTP()` is called, see here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L163

Comment: The error I'm getting is PHPMailer could not instantiate. what do you mean mail server? I'm using PHPMailer. and I will only use this on localhost only. do I need to setup STMP?

Comment: @TheTruth yes ! if you need the mail server to send the Mails, localhost doesn't have mail functionality until you mimic the server ! test your mail code in gmail server using phpmailer.

Comment: @leepowers fair call, i have never used it not to use a SMTP mailserver, otherwise why not just use mail()